# Al ejecutar da -1.#IND00. ¿Es error de código?

Tags: c, bucle-for, variables

Este programa ya llevo rato haciéndolo pero a la hora de ejecutar y dar de ejemplo x=90 y n=5 me regresa el valor 1.#IND00.

El programa se trata de series con factoriales, intenté hacerlo con series modificadas de Taylor pero mejor decidí usar la fórmula que está comentada.

Igualmente pueden encontrar los "prototipos" de la operación que realicé.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <locale.h> //libreria para acentos
#include <wchar.h>  //libreria para acentos

int leeValido(char * letrero);
int factorial(int numero);
float calculaSerie(int x, int n);
void  imprimeResultados(int x, int n, float resultado);

int main()
{
    int x, n;
    float resultado;
    system("color 03");
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    
    x = leeValido("Para x: ");
    n = leeValido("\nNúmero de iteraciones: ");
    resultado = calculaSerie(x,n);
    imprimeResultados(x, n, resultado);

    return 0;
}

int leeValido(char * letrero)
{
    int numero;
    
    do
    {
        printf("%s", letrero);
        scanf("%d", &numero);
    } while ((numero < 1) || (numero-numero > 0)); //no va a dejar de preguntar hasta que sea positivo
    
    return numero;
}

float calculaSerie(int x, int n)
{
    int i;
    float termino, suma = 0;
    
    //formula n E i=0
    //(-1)^i * x^2i/(2i)!= x^0/0! - x^2/2! + x^4/4! -x^6/6! + ...
    
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        //modelos varios:
        //termino = pow(x,i) / factorial(i*2);
        //termino = (pow(-1,i)) * (pow(x,2*i) / factorial(2*i));
        //termino = (-pow(termino,i)) * (pow(x,i)/factorial(suma));
        
        termino = (pow(-termino,i) * pow(x,2*i)) / factorial(2*i);
        
        suma += termino;
    }
    
    //printf("%f", termino);
    
    return suma;
}

int factorial (int numero)
{
    int factoriale, i;
    factoriale = 1;
    
    for(i=1 ; i<=numero ; i++)
    {
        factoriale *= i;
    }
    
    return factoriale;
}

void  imprimeResultados(int x, int n, float resultado)
{
    system("cls");
    printf("El resultado es x = %d con %d iteraciones es: %f", x, n, resultado);
}
```

Mi pregunta es, es error de código o se trata del tamaño de las variables.
Por que según mis cálculos, con el ejemplo me debe de dar -0.000001.

De antemano, gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema que tienes es que no has inicializado `termino` en ningún momento:

```
float calculaSerie(int x, int n)
{
    float termino;
    
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        termino = (pow(-termino,i) * pow(x,2*i)) / factorial(2*i);
        
        suma += termino;
    }
    
    return suma;
}
```

`termino` tendrá un valor basura que afecta al resultado de tu algoritmo. Para lidiar con estos despistes es preferible dar un valor a las variables en el momento de declararlas:

```
float termino = 0.0;
```

Es mejor hacerlo así a darle valor en líneas posteriores:

```
int factoriale, i;
factoriale = 1;
```

Ya que en este caso es facil acabar metiendo instrucciones entre la declaración y la inicialización ... y algunas de esas instrucciones pueden acabar usando una variable sin inicializar.

Comment: He realizado lo que sugieres pero no noto diferencia alguna.
Me sigue dando el valor `-1.#IND00` al ejecutar el programa. ):

Comment: Yo no se con qué valor debes inicializar `termino`. Igual el valor inicial debe ser `1`, `0.5` ... por otro lado, deberías imprimir los valores que va tomando `termino`. Eso te dará pistas acerca del motivo por el que obtienes ese valor

Comment: Lo que también he optado por hacer es colocar lo siguiente:
`suma += 1.00/termino;`

Comment: Piensa que nosotros podemos buscar errores en el código, pero no podemos estar en tu lugar y determinar si un algoritmo es válido o no. En ocasiones sí se puede porque es algo obvio, pero no algo que vaya a pasar siempre